# Safe way to terminate exposed electrical during remodel?

Tags: electrical, nec

I have a few exposed electrical wires that were cut in order to remove wiring in the area being remodeled. Is there a safe alternative to terminating all these points inside boxes? I need them safely capped off with wire nuts for about 3 months, and adding boxes seems overkill.

Maybe I'm just wishing there was some sort of product that was a bit lighter duty for short-term applications. Before I go buy a bunch of boxes and spend a good number of hours, I just want to be sure I couldn't get away with something simpler. Any ideas?

Comment: I take it you're trying to childproof this, since otherwise wire nuts -- plus electrical tape if you want. Or need additional protection -- would be an adequate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would also do wire nuts with electrical tape if I knew who was working in the area and they were competent.
The boxes you put your wires into don't need to be mounted anywhere. They can just be hanging around. But yes I understand cost and driving to get the boxes and covers can be a nuisance.
I know some people like to wire nut the hot and neutral together. That way if somebody turned the breaker on by accident, they would short out and not electrocute anybody. Again that would be wire nut and tape...

Comment: They *should* short out and not electrocute anybody.  If you're unlucky, the breaker isn't up to snuff, and they short out and start a fire.

Comment: Never thought of it that way.